# Using scale_shape_manual hides my regression line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently working on a correlation plot where I want to include both the correlation (including shading for the confidence interval) as well as the for each data point. Using ggplot2 and the following code, I get 16 different shapes (not my choice), one for each data point, but no regression line:

```
  ggplot(my_data_1500, aes(x = EC50, y = threshold, color = factor(compound), shape = factor(compound))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0:15)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste(EC[50]," (µM)"))) +
  labs(y = expression ("Threshold (µg/kg water)")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0), size = 28)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), size = 28)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 24)) +
  geom_smooth(colour = "black", method = lm)
```

Colored shapes:
[image]

If I change the code by removing the color and shape arguments from ggplot(), I get the line and dots, but the latter are identical:

```
  ggplot(my_data_1500, aes(x = EC50, y = threshold)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0:15)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste(EC[50]," (µM)"))) +
  labs(y = expression ("Threshold (µg/kg water)")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 15, b = 0, l = 0), size = 28)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 15, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), size = 28)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 24)) +
  geom_smooth(colour = "black", method = lm)
```

Just the line:
[image]

I managed to create another figure with geom_text_repel (ggrepel), where I replaced the dots with numbers, that worked perfectly fine.

Anybody got an idea how I can display both the line and the shapes? I assume it might be a problem with the layers, but can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want an aesthetic to just affect one layer, you can move `aes()` to that layer instead of putting it in the global `ggplot()`.  For example, if you want colors and shapes for the points but one overall regression line you could put `aes(color = compound, shape = compound)` into the `geom_point()` layer.

Comment: Moving the aes() to both geom_point() and geom_smooth() did the trick, thanks for the tip!